# Why is Monroe and Rosalee's relationship taboo when others aren't?

Tags: grimm

Throughout the series we see several couples that are not the same species of wesen, in [*Season 3 Episode 10*](https://grimm.fandom.com/wiki/Eyes_of_the_Beholder) Alicia and Joe are different, Alicia is a Fuchsbau and Joe is a Klaustreich. Then the [*Season 1 Episode 16*](https://grimm.fandom.com/wiki/The_Thing_with_Feathers) we have a klaustreich married to a Seltenvogel. So, obviously there are cases when different wesen are allowed to be in a relationship with each other. Why then is Monroe and Rosalee's relationship considered Taboo and a subject of such contention in the show when they seek to get married?

Comment: Seltenvogel are so rare they are believed to be extinct, it's been a long time since I watch the episode, but I think the husband was controlling and manipulative to the point where the Seltenvogel was essentially a prisoner being held for the rare mineral she produces.

Comment: Speculatively, it might be relationships with Klaustreich males are not covered by the taboo due to their [irresistable](https://grimm.fandom.com/wiki/Klaustreich#Behavior) nature. The [script](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=14625) for 1x16 includes a reference to Monroe's old girlfriend and a Klaustreich, again the problem seemed to be behviour rather than taboo. I'll try turning these into an answer tonight if no one has any better ideas before then.

Comment: There is also the episode with the healer, where he is a Koschie and she is a Malin Fatal, showing it is more than just Klaustreich relationships